# Swift launch thread in background

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift2

I'm trying to send a process in a background thread using the following code:

```
let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)

dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
    print("running in the background queue")
    btDiscovery
})
```

but the class is only processing while begin in foreground...any idea ?

EDIT1:

btDiscovery is a class which performs a BLE device scan every X seconds:

```
let btDiscoverySharedInstance = Beacon();

class Beacon: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

private var centralManager: CBCentralManager?
private var peripheralBLE: CBPeripheral?
....


   func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
    switch (central.state) {
    case CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOff:
        print("BLE powered off")
        self.clearDevices()

    case CBCentralManagerState.Unauthorized:
        // Indicate to user that the iOS device does not support BLE.
        print("BLE not supported")
        break

    case CBCentralManagerState.Unknown:
        // Wait for another event
        print("BLE unknown event")
        break

    case CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn:
        print("BLE powered on")
            self.startScanning()
        break

    case CBCentralManagerState.Resetting:
        print("BLE reset")
        self.clearDevices()

    case CBCentralManagerState.Unsupported:
        print("BLE unsupported event")
        break
    }
}


    func startScanning() {
    print("Start scanning...")
        if let central = centralManager {
            central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
        }
    }

  func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {
    print("Discovered peripheral \(RSSI) dBM name: \(peripheral.name)")
    print("UUID: \(peripheral.identifier.UUIDString)")
    ...
    sleep(delayPolling)
    self.startScanning()
  }
```

when the app is launched and remains in foreground, the scan is performed correctly every "delayPolling" seconds.
but as soon as I put my app is background, the scan is paused. it restarts only when it comes back again in foreground.

I would need to leave this scan running in background every time (even if we set a lower priority to this thread).

EDIT2:

by reading the documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html

I can see that

*When an app that implements the central role includes the UIBackgroundModes key with the bluetooth-central value in its Info.plist file, the Core Bluetooth framework allows your app to run in the background to perform certain Bluetooth-related tasks. While your app is in the background you can still discover and connect to peripherals, and explore and interact with peripheral data. In addition, the system wakes up your app when any of the CBCentralManagerDelegate or CBPeripheralDelegate delegate methods are invoked*

I selected the corresponding options in my Info.plist file:

[image]

but my app is not running my thread in background.

Comment: What is 'while begin'? How do you know it's executing in the foreground? Try adding a breakpoint to the block; the debugger can show what thread & queue is being executed when it stops on the breakpoint.

Comment: Do you mean while your app is in the background?  That isn't what QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND means on iOS. It just means a lower priority queue, but it still only executes while your app is running in the foreground. Can you explain more clearly what you are trying to do?

Comment: btDiscovery is a class which performs BLE devices scanning. centralManagerDidUpdateState (contained in the btDiscovery class) is never called when my app is in Background. will try with debugger. In foreground, the scan is performed correctly but as soon as I put my app in background, the scan is stopped and restarted when the app comes back in the foreground

Comment: may be you need more details to help me ?

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old question, but scanning in the background requires that you supply a Service UUID.

```
central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
```

needs to be

```
central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(serviceUUID, options: nil)
```